# MySQL/MariaDB - Is it possible to convert a list of strings into column values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot

I'm using both MySQL community as well as MariaDB.

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS "No of Orders",
       COUNT(po_id) AS "No of Production Orders",
       SUM(po_qty) AS "No of Tools"
  FROM orders
  JOIN production_orders ON po_o_id=order_id
 WHERE order_type="Trial"
   AND (po_status <> "COMPLETED"
   AND po_status <> "GOODS_ISSUED"
   AND po_status <> "PO_TERMINATED"
   AND po_status IS NOT NULL);
```

I get the following output when I run the query:

| No of Orders | No of Production Orders | No of Tools |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 271 | 321 | 2335 |

My question is, what should I do to get the output in this way - that is, turning the rows into column values:

| Labels | Values |
| --- | --- |
| No of Orders | 271 |
| No of Production Orders | 321 |
| No of Tools | 2335 |

Is it even possible to orient the query output this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can split your query in three separates, one for each value and use UNION ALL between them.

Comment: Do this on the client side.

Comment: @Jonas Metzler Thanks for the input, I have got it working now.